# Phonegap serve Ubuntu 17 not working/exiting silently

Tags: linux, cordova, ubuntu, phonegap, serve

Using ubuntu 17. Firewall is completely disabled using `sudo ufw disable`

Ive `sudo npm -g install phonegap` and created a project using `sudo phonegap create`.
From this stock created project i try to `sudo phonegap serve`, the terminal is still for 2 seconds then the command exits silently with no error message.

I have also tried cordova and have done the exact same steps
`install` `create` `serve`, I get further the application seems to serve. I can get on the website and on the browser of my phone and can see the project directory. When I get on the phonegap developer app to check the project out, I enter my laptops ip and port, I seem to get through but the app responds with "Unable to download archive from server" and on the serve console I get a `404 /__api__/appzip`.